# Found files htdocs without open XAMPP

Tags: php, macos, file, xampp, finder

I have a problem with XAMPP for Mac OS.
And sorry I'm French, so I don't really speak English.

When I want open XAMPP, I have a mistake **XAMPP Error 137**, and after spend my time on this forum, I found why. I have a beta version of MACOS, and I realized that it was because of the beta version that the application did not open.

I would like to found the file HTDOCS to file my script...if I can't find this file I have lost a big project in progress.

Please help me, my question is, how open on Mac htdocs without open XAMPP.

Comment: It simple, open finder and go to application window then find xampp folder. You will find all of them rest folder as well.

Comment: Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: Hi, I suggest you to read this link to learn how to submit a good question to Stackoverflow.
In this way you can get more probabilities to get answers and your question not to be closed.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you can use the the orginal way

go to

```
Finder->Applications->XAMPP->htdocs
```

or by using this command in terminal :

```
 open /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs
```

or by using launchpad by typying

```
  htdocs
```

Comment: Thank you but when I go to /Applications/XAMPP I have just Contents, then when I open I have Frameworks, MacOS, PlugIns, Ressources

Answer (score 0):

Thank you but when I go to /Applications/XAMPP I have just Contents, then when I open I have Frameworks, MacOS, PlugIns, Ressources